# Ways to draw 3 balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, data-analysis

A box contains 2 white balls, 3 black balls and 4 red balls. In how many ways can 3 balls be drawn from the box, if at least one black ball is to be included in the draw?

My logic: total ways to draw 3 balls which is 9C3 - the case which does not have any black ball which is 6C2
So according to me answer is 
9C3 - 6C2 = 84 -15= 69

But answer is something else. Please help

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into difficulties?

Comment: 9C3 would be the ways to draw 3 balls if all the balls contained in the box were different. In this problem, two balls of the same color are to be considered indistinguishable. E.g. If you were to draw just one ball, the ways to do that would not be 9C1 = 9, but 3: the ball that you will draw can be either white, black or red.

Comment: You say "*the answer is something else.*"  Share with us that answer and that might give clues to us as to how the problem writer interpreted the problem.  Otherwise, we need to ask for a good deal of clarification such as *does order matter* and *are balls distinguishable*? etc...

Comment: As for your attempt, $\binom{9}{3}$ is the number of ways in which you can draw three balls assuming order doesn't matter and balls are all distinguishable.  $\binom{6}{\color{red}{3}}$ is the number of ways of drawing *three* balls from only the $2$ white and $4$ red available, i.e. the number of ways of having drawn *no* black balls.  So, you should have gotten $\binom{9}{3}-\binom{6}{\color{red}{3}}$, not $\binom{9}{3}-\binom{6}{2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz This was the solution given - We may have(1 black and 2 non-black) or (2 black and 1 non-black) or (3 black).

Comment: That is not the whole solution.  Include the whole solution including final numbers.

Comment: Required number of ways= (3C1 x 6C2) + (3C2 x 6C1) + (3C3)

Comment: That clarifies now that we are treating the balls as distinguishable and order doesnt' matter finally.  Now, notice... $\binom{9}{3}-\binom{6}{3}=64$ is exactly equal to $\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{3}{3}=64$, seen either by direct computation or even faster by [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).  Your only mistake was either a typo or a lack of attention in using $\binom{6}{2}$ rather than $\binom{6}{3}$

Comment: Thanks I got my mistake. I was taking 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing comments, your answer and approach is perfectly valid (*and indeed the one I recommend as it saves time with computation*), taking the number of outcomes overall without restriction, and subtracting away those outcomes where no blacks were drawn at all.

This gives a total of $$\binom{9}{3}-\binom{6}{3}=64$$

You could have done as the solutions author you are citing did and approached directly, breaking into cases based on the total number of blacks selected.  This is all well and good and arrives at the same answer, but requires noticeably more computation, especially if we were to extend the problem to asking about drawing at least one black ball when all of the other numbers in the problem were much larger.

Notice:

$$\binom{9}{3}=\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{0}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{6}{1}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{6}{0}\binom{3}{3}$$

seen by [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) and so

$$\binom{9}{3}-\binom{6}{3}=\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{6}{1}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{3}$$

and so the answers are in fact the same, just written differently.

Your only mistake was either a typo or a lack of focus and using $\binom{6}{2}$ in place of $\binom{6}{3}$ in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If a black ball must be included, the problem equals to draw $2$ balls from a box with $2$ black, $2$ white and $4$ red. So you have this six options:

Black Black.

White White.

Red Red.

Black White.

Black Red.

White Red.

Comment: I know the solution. But I want to know what is wrong with my logic.

Comment: It may be that you dont have to consider balls of the same color as different. That reduces the possible cases a lot.